# What is MailChimp Responsive issue?

Tags: html, email-templates

This is my code.

https://codepen.io/rajibmridhabapy/pen/YjqWme

I am trying to figure out the responsive problem. It's looks fine on browser responsive and also mobile but the problem is when i use MailChimp and send to my gmail that time it's not responsive. 
The most important think is that when i created a template by past my own code in Mailchimp and for check i sent it to my gmail it's looks fine. but when i saved it and then send it. It's lost responsive. 
I can't figure out what's the main problem.

Though i change some coding for full width color and it's good though in my browser. How can i solve it. please let me know.

I don't have much more idea about HTML Email template and Mail Chimp. But last 2 days i wanted to know. and fixed size 600px it's g`enter code here`ood. but i seen some template has full screen section background and i tried to do it.

Comment: try removing the space before `480px`. Gmail is very picky on these things.